# How to calculate discount

Tags: java, oop, methods

So i am trying to create a method called currentValue(), this method should calculate the current value of a video game with the a discount percentage of 30percent a year. Now the problem is with the foor loop it just keeps giving the same amount of discount over the new value, what it want it to do is give the second year of discount over the already discounted price the year before.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should probably include your code.

Answer (score 0):

This will give the discount on the discounted price.

```js
let price = 100; //current year price;
let n = 5; // no. of years;
for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    price = price - ((price * 30)/100); // discounted price;
    console.log(price);
}
```